# Use clang to compile code with gnu directives

Tags: assembly, clang, gnu

Is it possible to compile this code with clang so that it does not produce the "unknown directive" error?

```
.list
.text
.globl _main
.align 16, 0x90
_main:
ret
.nolist
```

**Edited:**

clang version 3.6.2.

test.s:1:1: error: unknown directive
.list

test.s:7:1: error: unknown directive
.nolist

Comment: What version, and what is the error?

Comment: See [mcve].  Good minimal test-case, but like Jester said you need to give more detail on the error and clang version.

Comment: I apologize, I'll take this into account in the future

Comment: Clang is a C/C++ compiler and this is assembler.

Comment: @arrowd : What makes you think clang (like GCC) won't assemble code? If you name a file with the `.s` (or `.S` if one needs CPP processing) extension `llvm-as` will be used to assemble the code if done through `clang` . From the perspective of the user `clang` will appear to assemble code. GCC will do something similar.

Comment: Remove `.list` and `.nolist` ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I understand it. The question is, is there a way to use the clang to compile a file with all gnu directives, or llvm-as can't do this?

Comment: Appears llvm's assembler doesn't understand all GNU directives. Yoiu should be able to remove `.list` and `.nolist` directives and it will likely work.